# Comparison of two SQL tables in one datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare two different SQL tables `Esimation` and `Actual Cost`. Columns / rows of both tables are the same.

How can I compare both tables showing in one datagridview as column names of SQL tables in first column as row values and `Estimation` and `Actual Cost` as column names of Gridview.

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ck33.jpg)

Comment: you should ideally do this in SQL directly against your DB. If so, show your tables and SQL statements, and add the SQL and your RDBMS' tags to the question

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow, please clearify your question, but it seems you need to know Sql JOIN.

Comment: As per the other comments, doing it in your SQL would be the way forward. But you might also consider your db design - from the info you've given, it might be that Estimation and Actual Cost could be fields of one table rather than in two separate tables.

Comment: Its two separate tables.We have "estimation" filled before executing the work.We will fill "Actual cost" table after executing it.Then we need to compare each items like material cost,Transportation charges,Over head,Profit etc

Comment: You lost me at the word "showing" everything after that makes no sense to me.

Comment: I have attached an image.I think that will give you a clear idea of what I am asking.

Comment: I think you need a SQL query which INNER JOINs the two tables together based on the Job ID.

Comment: ADyson,But it will spread every thing horizontally.I need vertically as given in the image.

Comment: Sounds like you need a cross table (pivot table),  will there only be one of "JobNo" in the dataset? IE will job A appear more than once in the rowset? Seems odd to call it JobNo then have a alpha value

Comment: @SreeKanth you could inner join them, and then pivot that query as Mr Tripodi suggests

Comment: @Mr.Tripodi, Unpivot (Both tables) and left join gives the result.Thanks for suggestion as I was not aware of Pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach is a join but as you've commented above, that gives a horizontal grid and you want it vertically.

So I think this approach should work, although I'm not sure how efficient it is so you need to test that for yourself against your dataset.

```
select 'Material' as Description, Estimation.Material as Estimation, ActualCost.Material as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo
UNION 
select 'Fabrication' as Description, Estimation.Fabrication as Estimation, ActualCost.Fabrication as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo
UNION 
select 'Transporation' as Description, Estimation.Transporation as Estimation, ActualCost.Transporation as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo
UNION 
select 'OH' as Description, Estimation.OH as Estimation, ActualCost.OH as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo
UNION 
select 'Profit' as Description, Estimation.Profit as Estimation, ActualCost.Profit as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo
```

I've not run that query so can't promise it's 100% but it will hopefully put you on the right track

If you don't want to use the UNION SQL command for any reason, you could do the same thing in VB like this (although it's a bit clumsy)

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Using da As New SqlDataAdapter("select 'Material' as Description, Estimation.Material as Estimation, ActualCost.Material as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo", New SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("JobNo", YourJobNo)
        da.Fill(dt)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select 'Fabrication' as Description, Estimation.Fabrication as Estimation, ActualCost.Fabrication as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo"
        da.Fill(dt)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select 'Transporation' as Description, Estimation.Transporation as Estimation, ActualCost.Transporation as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo"
        da.Fill(dt)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select 'OH' as Description, Estimation.OH as Estimation, ActualCost.OH as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo"
        da.Fill(dt)
        da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select 'Profit' as Description, Estimation.Profit as Estimation, ActualCost.Profit as ActualCost from ActualCost INNER JOIN Estimation on ActualCost.JobNo = Estimation.JobNo Where ActualCost.JobNo=@JobNo"
        da.Fill(dt)
End Using
```

Comment: I did not try the second one as the first one worked perfectly